# Showing a set is open but it is not closed on the complex plane

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

LEt $D = \{ z : \operatorname{Im} z > 2 \} $.

D is open:

Let $z \in D $ be arbitrary. We know $\operatorname{Im} z  - 2 >0$. Let $\epsilon = \operatorname{Im} z - 2 $. Can show $D( z, \epsilon ) \subset D $. Let $w \in D(z, \epsilon )$. If we can show $\operatorname{Im} w > 2 $ then we are done. I know that $|\operatorname{Im} w - \operatorname{Im} z| = | \operatorname{Im}(w - z) | \leq |w-z| < \epsilon $. But this does not seem to help me. How can I show that $\operatorname{Im} w > 2 $?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $|\mathrm{Im}(w) - \mathrm{Im}(z)| < \epsilon$, then $\mathrm{Im}(z) -\epsilon < \mathrm{Im}(w) < \mathrm{Im}(z) + \epsilon$. In particular, $\mathrm{Im}(w) > \mathrm{Im}(z) - \epsilon = 2$, so $w\in D$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f:\Bbb C\to \Bbb R$ définied by $f(z)=\dfrac{z-\bar{z}}{2i}=\mathrm{Im}(z)$.

$f$ is continuous. Then 
$D=f^{-1}((2,+\infty))$ is open (since $(2,+\infty)$ is open in $\Bbb R$).